# phpmyadmin site on macOSSierra errno: 13 - Permission denied

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

The following error and few more errors come up when I log into phpmyadmin. At the same time database listing also empty. It is also not allowing new database creation.

> in ./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.php#184 mysqli_query(): (HY000/1018): Can't read dir of '.' (errno: 13 - Permission denied) Backtrace ./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.php#184: mysqli_query( , string 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SCHEMA_NAME, \'_\', 1) DB_first_level FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE TRUE ) t ', integer 0,

This was started after upgrade of php and apache in macOSSierra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is error occurs when **/usr/local/mysql** folder doesn't have not enough permission.
You can fix this by changing permissions using the following command

```
chmod -R 755 ./mysql
```